# Boostrap dropdown menu and toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got this bootstrap admin panel theme from github, it is all written in html file. I have this site of mine (I am also using codeigniter php framework) where I want to apply the bootstrap theme that I downloaded from git.

Now, the problem is after I apply it to the site I've been working on, all are working except for the dropdown menu and the menu toggle. I tested it first if it's working before I applied it to my site, and everything was fine.

I already tried the suggestions from other posts that have the same problem with mine, such as putting `jquery.min.js` first before the `bootstrap.min.js`. But still not working.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>NEH </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/animate.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/custom.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.1.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/icheck/flat/green.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/floatexamples.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js') ?>"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>
```

the sidebar menu part:

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

                        <div class="menu_section">
                            <h3>General</h3>
                            <ul class="nav side-menu">
                                <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="index3.html">Dashboard3</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li><a><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Tables <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                        <li><a href="tables.html">Tables</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="tables_dynamic.html">Table Dynamic</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

Comment: Check your browser console for the errors.

Comment: Is there any*js errors* ?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola how to do that?

Comment: Press `F12` if you are using firefox or chrome.

Comment: @ash_8247 Do you mean displayed errors? Or not? Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean. I am not really familiar with js.

Comment: Your browser console shows you error regarding your javascripts.

Comment: Thank you. Got it working now :) I just mistype the directory name.